# How do I access a JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have a PHP script to which I make an Ajax request, and most of it works okay, but I'm having trouble accessing an array in the data returned to the JavaScript function.

So, the PHP has a bunch of regular variables, and one array. The array, $places, has four elements, which each have three values, as so:

```
[["z","815","1"],["w","2813","0"],["s","1582","2"],["b","1220","5"]]
```

A relevant excerpt of the PHP script is:

```
$encoded_places = json_encode($places);  // if I don't do this then I end up with a value of "Array"
$qobject->name = "$name";
$qobject->multi = "$multi";
$qobject->places= "$encoded_places";

$myJSON = json_encode($qobject);
echo $myJSON;
```

In the JavaScript script (using JQuery), I successfully obtain the data from the Ajax request, and I can access all the data okay, except the $places data.

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(data, status){

   var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
   var parsedObj = JSON.parse(stringified);

   var x = parsedObj.name; // alert(x);  // which works fine

   var myArray = new Array();
   myArray.push(parsedObj.places);

   for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        console.log(myArray[i]);
   }
```

... and the console will display what I'm expecting, namely:

```
[["z","815","1"],["w","2813","0"],["s","1582","2"],["b","1220","5"]]
```

However, I'm having difficulty accessing these values. For example, supposing I try to access the "815" portion of the first element, with something like: myArray[0][1], all I end up with is "[".

I guess somehow this whole piece of data is just a string, instead of an array, but I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to quite know how to progress.

If, for example, I do this in the JavaScript script (hoping to see 815, 2813, 1582 and 1220 in the alerts) all I'll see is the single alert with "[". (i.e. it does the loop only once, and selects the character in position 1).

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    alert(myArray[i][1]);                                                                                                             
}
```

I would very much appreciate someone explaining:
(a) how I can access the individual elements and values in JS
(b) how I can loop through them, although presumably once it's an array and not a string then the code above should do this.

Many thanks for any assistance.

**Now Resolved:**
As noted by @charlietfl, below, using quotes in

```
$qobject->places= "$encoded_places";
```

screwed things up, along with using json_encode on $places. However, without removing the quotes nothing worked either way. So, removed quotes and just used json_encode on the entire structure at the end, which now works fine.

So, the original snippet of code, given above, now looks like:

```
$qobject->name = $name;
$qobject->multi = $multi;
$qobject->places= $places;

$myJSON = json_encode($qobject);
echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof parsedObj.places)` give you? Also, you don't need to create a new `Array` since it appears that it's already an array, and `myArray.push` will just push that whole array into the first position of the new `Array`, not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Don't json_encode the $places. Just let `$myJSON = json_encode($qobject);` do all the serializing. What you are getting is nested json string when parsed instead of the array you think you are getting

Comment: console.log(typeof parsedObj.places); // String

Comment: Then you should do `var myArray = JSON.parse(parsedObj.places)` - ultimately the issue is related to what @charlietfl had mentioned

Comment: @goto1 The parsing is done internally with `$.getJSON`

Comment: @charlietfl if it's done recursively then I guess that's fine, but `JSON.parse` will not pick up nested arrays that are represented as strings, and in this case that seems to be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$qobject->places = "$encoded_places";
```

To

```
$qobject->places = $places;
```

And get rid of the `$encoded_places = json_encode($places);` so that the one call to json_encode serializes the whole structure

Comment: Thank you, but if I get rid of the $encoded_places bit, and have just the single call to json_encode, serializing the whole structure, then I seem even worse off, since rather than give any data at all, console.log(myArray[i]) just gives "Array" (rather than the string of values), and  console.log(typeof parsedObj.places) still gives "String".

Comment: What does `print_r($places)` look like? And did you quote `"$places"` because that would be incorrect

Comment: Good call with the quotes! Yes, that's exactly what it was. Without amending anything  else I was able to make it work by removing the quotes from "$encoded_places". Many thanks indeed!!! Not sure how/if I can accept your comment as an answer, but I'm greatly appreciative. Thank you. Will check back later for any other comments.

Comment: Still shouldn't need encoded_places and should be able to only json_encode once

Comment: True; I see I used $places, rather than $encoded_places as I was testing the quotes, and so yes, I guess that's a second thing I changed; so, no quotes, and only the single json_encode before outputting. Thank you again.

Comment: So the other answers are band-aids to try to do multiple parsings....mine solves the issue at server and delivers what you were originally expecting to client with no additional parsing needed. Feel free to accept answer if it helps

Comment: Yup, accepted. Thanks a lot! Afraid I don't have any superpowers to upvote or anything though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$.getJSON(url, function(data, status){
  var parsedObj = JSON.parse(stringified);

  console.table(parsedObj.places);
  console.log(parsedObj.places)[0][0];
}
```

In the posted code's `getJSON` context, `data` is already a JSON string. So this line is redundantly stringifying your JSON string:

```js
var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
```

`stringified` is now set to a literal/escaped version of the valid JSON string from the `data` parameter:

```
  [[\"z\",\"815\",\"1\"],[\"w\",\"2813\",\"0\"],[\"s\",\"1582\",\"2\"],[\"b\",\"1220\",\"5\"]]
```

When that double-stringified value is passed to `JSON.parse` for the `parsedObj` reference, it just becomes the original JSON string again (which looks deceptively correct in an alert box).

Strings are iterable in JavaScript, so the for loop was just going over the string.

Comment: That does somewhat make sense to me, especially the sneaky string iteration, but it doesn't work for me because of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" ... which reminds me of how I ended up doing what I did with JSON.stringify(data) / JSON.parse(stringified), which was given as the fix for that error here: https://thisinterestsme.com/fix-unexpected-token-o-in-json/

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, a quick fix could be to keep the original `stringify` and the use `parse` twice. But the better fix would be to ensure PHP returns a well-formed JSON string in the first place.